# r - Find corresponding value from multiple columns according to pmin in multiple columns

Tags: r

My df is sth like this:

```
Item    P   P1  P2   P3   D1    D2  D3   pmin   num     NP
A       10  8   11   20   2     1   10   1      D2      11
B       10  8   11   20   2     1   10   1      D2      11  
C       10  8   11   20   2     1   10   1      D2      11
D       50  40  35   70   10    15  20   10     D1      40
E       20  15  22   30   5     2   10   2      D2      22
```

As shown in my df above, I've first calculated D1 and D2, 'pmin' is the parallel min for D1 and D2, 'num' gives the column name(D1 or D2) corresponding to my pmin.

Now what I want is return a new column called 'NP' that gives me the corresponding values in P1 or P2 according to the pmin (by looking across the row). For example, if it says D2 in 'num', looking across the row, I return value from P2, if it says D1 in 'num', I return the value from P1.

Not sure if I explained it nicely but here's how I did for 'pmin' and 'num':

```
df$pmin = do.call(pmin, df[,5:6] )

df$num = apply(df[,5:6], 1,function(x) names(x)[which.min(x)])
```

Also in my real dataset, I have P1 through P4 and D1 through D4.

I tried sth like

```
ifelse( num == 'D1', P1, P2)
```

but it doesn't work for more than two columns (P1~P4..)

Thanks in advance!!

btw does anyone know how to use

```
case_when()
```

from library(dplyr) to get 'NP'?

Comment: Please see some guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible question. It's difficult for us to work with data that's shown in an image, but you can post the output of calling `dput` on a representative sample.

Comment: Sorry my first time using stackoverflow. I'll try to edit it again!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error mentioned.  Please check the data I used with the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing to extract the elements of 'P1/P2' columns that corresponds to the 'D1', 'D2'

```
m1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), match(df$num, c("D1", "D2", "D3")))
df$NP <- df[c("P1", "P2", "P3")][m1]
df$NP
#[1] 11 11 11 40 22
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Item = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), P = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 50L, 20L), P1 = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 40L, 15L), P2 = c(11L, 
11L, 11L, 35L, 22L), P3 = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 70L, 30L), D1 = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 10L, 5L), D2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 2L), D3 = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 20L, 10L), pmin = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 2L), num = c("D2", 
"D2", "D2", "D1", "D2"), NP = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 40L, 22L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Thank you!! :) but I got this Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing..my dataset actually have P1 through P4 and D1 ~ D4.. Is it because of that?

Comment: @ValentinaSapphire. If you have those, then change the code in the first line to `c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4")` and in second line to `c("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4")`

Comment: Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing
still got the same error :O

Comment: @ValentinaSapphire. Can you update your post with the `dput` of the example

Comment: @ValentinaSapphire Based on the example you showed, it is working for me.

Comment: , row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")

Comment: @ValentinaSapphire. Looks like you have `tbl_df`

Comment: Yes your code worked.. but this is whats on the end of my data frame. it contains other columns as well, like text descriptions and id number

Comment: @ValentinaSapphire. It doesn't matter because we are only subsetting the columns of interest

Comment: @ValentinaSapphire. As this is a `tibble` you can convert to data.frame and use the same code `as.data.frame(df[c("P1", "P2", "P3")])[m1]`